# ggplot2: Adjusting color scale to fit wide range of data

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I have raw data which looks something along the limes of this:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~agegroup, ~day1, ~day2, ~day3, ~day4,
  1, 20, 50, 21, 24,
  2, 23, 60, 25, 25,
  3, 26, 80, 14, 50,
  4, 23, 250, 300, 500,
  5, 50, 80, 280, 290,
)

df <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(!agegroup, names_to = "day", values_to = "incidence" )

> head(df, n = 10)
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   agegroup day   incidence
      <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
 1        1 day1         20
 2        1 day2         50
 3        1 day3         21
 4        1 day4         24
 5        2 day1         23
 6        2 day2         60
 7        2 day3         25
 8        2 day4         25
 9        3 day1         26
10        3 day2         80
```

Now I want to visualize this in a heatmap for example:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = day, y = agegroup), group = agegroup) +
  geom_bin2d(aes(fill = incidence), stat = 'identity')
```

The problem is, because some of the values are so far apart from the others (in agegroup 4 and 5), I lose all of the information in the lower agegroups:

[image: Plot 1]

Now, I thought I'd adjust `scale_fill_gradient`:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = day, y = agegroup), group = agegroup) +
  geom_bin2d(aes(fill = incidence), stat = 'identity') +
  scale_fill_gradient(limits = c(0,100))
```

However, in the result the incidence numbers >100 are "burnt out":

[image: Plot 2]

What would be the best way to visualize? Is there an easy way to group the data in chunks eg. 0-20, 20-40, ..., >200 for example?

Comment: Log scale the colour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `scale_fill_gradient2` (you can obviously choose nicer colours)?

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tribble(
  ~agegroup, ~day1, ~day2, ~day3, ~day4,
  1, 20, 50, 21, 24,
  2, 23, 60, 25, 25,
  3, 26, 80, 14, 50,
  4, 23, 250, 300, 500,
  5, 50, 80, 280, 290,
)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(!agegroup, names_to = "day", values_to = "incidence") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = day, y = agegroup), group = agegroup) +
  geom_bin2d(aes(fill = incidence), stat = 'identity') +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue",
                       mid = "white",
                       high = "red",
                       midpoint = 100)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

`scale_fill_gradient2` allows you to choose your own arbitrary midpoint, which means you can better visualize the differences in the lower incidence levels.

You can additionally apply a sensible transformation of the scale, such as `log10`:

```r
  ... +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue",
                       mid = "white",
                       high = "red",
                       midpoint = log10(100),
                       trans = "log10")
```

[image]